# How to fix install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in windows

Tags: windows, apache, perl

I have the following issue on Windows 7.

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in windows

I am using ActivePerl version 5.28 in my local set up.

When I print the drivers

```
 use DBI;

 my @ary = DBI->available_drivers();
```

It give below options.

> CSV DBM ExampleP File Gofer Mem ODBC Oracle Pg Proxy SQLite Sponge mysql

Whereas I am getting the above error while connecting to mysql db.

I have installed `DBI & DBD::mysql` through cpan. These modules got installed inside `cpan/build/DBI`

I have copied down the lib folder inside this build to Perl installation lib folder.

Is there something wrong here? Have I missed some steps?

Comment: Re "*I have copied down the lib folder inside this build to Perl installation lib folder.*", You appear to have incorrectly replicated by the installation process. By why did you try at all?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about installing modules on Windows, but...

> I have installed `DBI` & `DBD::mysql` through cpan. These modules got installed inside `cpan/build/DBI`

That's not the installation directory. That's an intermediate directory that `cpan` uses while building and installing a module.

> I have copied down the lib folder inside this build to Perl installation lib folder.

You shouldn't need to do that. One of the reasons for using `cpan` is that it carries out **all** of the installation steps for you. If that hasn't happened then there were very likely some problems in the installation.

Is there a log file for the installation? Did you see any error messages?

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in windows

This seems to imply that you don't have the MySQL client library installed. `DBD::mysql` uses this library to actually communicate with the database server. You might need to [install the library from here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/c-api/).

It's also worth reading the `DBD::msql` [installation guide](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod#BINARY-INSTALLATION). It says:

> **ActiveState Perl**
>
> ActivePerl offers a PPM archive of DBD::mysql. All you need to do is typing in a cmd.exe window:
>
> ```
> ppm install DBD-mysql
> ```

Comment: Current version of Activestate Perl 5.28 does not have PPM anymore. https://www.activestate.com/blog/goodbye-ppm-hello-state-tool/

Comment: @SuchetaP: Well that sucks. So you're back to installing the MySQL client library and taking it from there.

Comment: When I use this command perl -MDBD::mysql -le'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'  This below erros comes                                                                                    
Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Pe
rl64/lib C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at -e line 0.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: @SuchetaP: I know. You've said that. It's probably for the reason I've described in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami  dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.           dmake -- NOT OK                                                                                          This is the error i recieve while installing module so the installed files are not getting copied onto site/lib folder of perl installation. Then i manually copy the files. That also doesn't help.Can you please help to fix this. I have installed MinGW this also didn't help

Comment: @SuchetaP: So it looks like you don't have `dmake` installed. What happens if you run `cpan dmake`?

Comment: Unfortunately that also fails.

Comment: I am doing installation on windows 2007 server.. It was a proxy too. Please help me how can I make the dmake command work on this server.

Comment: @SuchetaP: You really can't just say "that also fails" and expect to get any reasonable help. How did it fail? What unexpected behaviour did you see? Were there any error messages? Please update your question with useful information like this.